# Notification status suddenly "undetermined" for all builds

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am building an ejected Expo app (React Native w/ ExpoKit), and have recently run into an issue with notifications. I had them working previously with no issue, but recently, that suddenly changed, even though I didn't change anything relating to the notifications. Note that I am only using local notifications.

Anytime I try to add a notification, I get an "undetermined" status code, thus I can't add register notifications. This happens in the simulator, app built on device, and app distributed through TestFlight.

I tried downloading an older app version from TestFlight that had worked no problem before, but now I get the "undetermined" code on that version to! Does this mean that my device is the issue?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I did not have push notification entitlement configured, and adding that seemed to fix the issue. I’m still unsure why it worked before and suddenly stopped though.